# How much hard drive space is needed for Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows-8, cpu

I want to install both Windows 8 and Linux on my PC and was was wondering what is the minimum amount of hard drive space that I will need to accomplish this.  Also, are there any apparent pros/cons to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu minimum requirements:
5 GB of hard-drive space

Windows 8 minimum requirements: 
16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit) of hard-drive space

So you would need a computer with at least 1x 25GB hard drive.
Of course you should probably have more if you would like to do things like install programs.

---

The only con to this type of setup is that you can only run on OS at a time. If you ran on OS as a host and the other in a VM (Virtual Machine) you could have them both running at the same time.
A pro is that the two systems, because they don't run at the same time, also don't share memory between them. So you could potentially see a performance increase compared to running one in a VM.

Comment: Note that if you want the *bare minimum* there are versions of linux that take up much less space.

Comment: That is correct. I was quoting from Ubuntu Desktop Edition as this is a common install. You could install server only with no GUI and only need 1GB for example.